# What should I do if i don't want to get 'none' in out put after using a function

Tags: python, function

I wrote this code which gives multiplication table .But in output I get '*none*' ,what should I do to not get '*none*'

```
def table(n):
    for i in range(1,6):
        j=i*n
        x = print(f"{i} * {n} = {j}")
    return x
print(table(int(input("enter the number :"))))
```

**output**

```
enter the number :4
1 * 4 = 4
2 * 4 = 8
3 * 4 = 12
4 * 4 = 16
5 * 4 = 20
None
```

What should I do to not get '`None`'

Comment: Please, fix the indentation first.

Comment: don't print the return of `table()`

Comment: Please correct the indentation. Also, ```print``` returns ```None``` which is assigned to ```x```. which is what you are returning

Comment: get rid of `return x` and return `table(int(input("enter the number :")))` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning the `print` function to `x`. Since `print` returns `None`, you are assigning `x` `None`, then you are returning `x`.

Also, `return` will end the function so don't use `return`

And also, remove the `print` function from the  `print(table....`.

```
def table(n):
    for i in range(1,6):
        j=i*n
        print(f"{i} * {n} = {j}")
table(int(input("enter the number :")))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try without writing `print` twice, also try without returning `x`:

```
def table(n):
    for i in range(1,6):
        j=i*n
        print(f"{i} * {n} = {j}")
table(int(input("enter the number :")))
```

Comment: "Writing `print` twice" is far from the reason why the OP is getting 'None` in the output.

Comment: Your edit still does not address why the OP is getting `None`. "Writing `print` twice" really simply has no direct relevance to the OP's issue.